# std::unordered_map and linker errors

Tags: c++, dll, linker

I'm have some problems with compiling my new project.

Compiler outputs:

```
1>------ Build started: Project: IRPCore, Configuration: Debug Win32 ------
1>  core.cpp
1>     Creating library D:\Repo\Inter Role Play Gamemode\sa-mp-0.2-plugin-sdk\IRP\Debug\IRPCore.lib and object D:\Repo\Inter Role Play Gamemode\sa-mp-0.2-plugin-sdk\IRP\Debug\IRPCore.exp
1>core.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: static class std::tr1::unordered_map<int,struct item,class std::hash<int>,struct std::equal_to<int>,class std::allocator<struct std::pair<int const ,struct item> > > core::itemCache" (?itemCache@core@@2V?$unordered_map@HUitem@@V?$hash@H@std@@U?$equal_to@H@3@V?$allocator@U?$pair@$$CBHUitem@@@std@@@3@@tr1@std@@A)
1>main.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: static class std::tr1::unordered_map<int,struct item,class std::hash<int>,struct std::equal_to<int>,class std::allocator<struct std::pair<int const ,struct item> > > core::itemCache" (?itemCache@core@@2V?$unordered_map@HUitem@@V?$hash@H@std@@U?$equal_to@H@3@V?$allocator@U?$pair@$$CBHUitem@@@std@@@3@@tr1@std@@A)
1>D:\Repo\Inter Role Play Gamemode\sa-mp-0.2-plugin-sdk\IRP\Debug\IRPCore.dll : fatal error LNK1120: 1 unresolved externals
```

Here comes core.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include <unordered_map>
#include "core.h"

core::core(void)
{

}

core::~core(void)
{

}

void core::Item_Insert(int uid, item Item)
{
    core::itemCache.insert(std::make_pair<int,item>(uid, Item));

    return;
}

std::string core::convertNativeStringToString(AMX *amx, cell input)
{
    char *string = NULL;
    amx_StrParam(amx, input, string);
    return string ? string : "";
}
```

Should I link some more libs or so?

Thanks in advance.

**Edit:** Here comes core definition from core.h

```
class core
{
    public:
        static std::unordered_map<int, item> itemCache;
        core(void);
        ~core(void);
        static void Item_Insert(int uid, item Item);
        static std::string convertNativeStringToString(AMX *amx, cell input);
    private:
};
```

Answer (score 8):

Add a definition of `core::itemCache` to core.cpp. In general, static data members of classes are **declared** in the class definition and **defined** in a source file.

Comment: But he showed his source file where he defined it and he includes a core.h that probably declares the class. I think his itemcache is not static and he doesnt instantiate it. But im not sure, im curious about the error.

Comment: @JonathanCruz: I see a source file, but I don't see it defined anywhere.  He includes core.h which probably _declares_ the variable, but globals/statics should not be defined in headers.

Comment: Declaration of class and struct item are im core.h

Comment: @Kacper - yes, that's what I guessed. Nevertheless, you need to **define** the static data member in a source file.

Comment: @JonathanCruz - the error refers to a static data member named `core::itemCache`. It says that it's not defined.

Comment: @Kacper - once again: you **declare** it in the header (as core.h shows) and you must **define** it in a source file. That means changing core.cpp.

Answer (score 8):

As @Pete Becker is saying, put this at the top of the cpp:

```
std::unordered_map<int, item> core::itemCache;
```

in addition to the

```
static std::unordered_map<int, item> itemCache;
```

already in the .h.